# How to add a placeholder to my Google Custom Searchbox?

Tags: javascript

I tried with another codes I found here but nothing worked.

This is my searchbox regular code:

```
<script async="" src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=008573911755377469615:xhdlwjbvh7o"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the attribute when window load.

```
window.onload = myCustomPlaceholder;

function myCustomPlaceholder() {
    document.getElementById("gsc-i-id1").setAttribute("placeholder", "my custom search placeholder")
}
```